# How can I retrieve the text of an li element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to retrieve the text of an li element using jquery for (eg. Events) and display it. How can I do that? My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="t-item t-state-active">
<a class="t-link" href="#TabStrip-5">Happening</a>
</li>
<li class="t-item t-state-active">
<a class="t-link" href="#TabStrip-5">Birthday</a>
</li>
<li class="t-item t-state-active">
<a class="t-link" href="#TabStrip-5">Events</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Please see implementation below

```
function Gettext() {
    var tabstrip = $("#TabStrip").data("tTabStrip");
    $("li", tabstrip.element).each(function () {
        var item = $(this)[0];
         if (item.textContent == 'Events'
           return tabstrip.select(item);
    });
```

But I want to optimize the code

Comment: `$(':contai' + 'ns(' + 'Ev' + 'en' + 'ts' + ')').show();`

Comment: sorry not so familiar with this one.

Comment: I was in a good mood, so I reformatted this to actually be a question.

Comment: Where is the #TabStrip element in your markup ?

Comment: I must say, you're doing this whole jQuery thing all wrong

Comment: You replied to my answer saying you don't want to use .each(), is there any particular reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the class of the element (eg `$('.classname')`) or the Id (eg `$('#id')`), then call the `text()` function

```
$('.classname').text();
$('#id').text();
```

For events, you could do:

```
$('.t-link:last-child').text();
```

But I would recommend adding an Id for a singleton like that:

```
<a class="t-link" href="#TabStrip-5" id="events-link">Events</a>
```

then...

```
$('#events-link').text();
```

**EDIT**

For dynamic positions, you definitely want to assign IDs to each cell if you're trying to grab an individual cell.

Maybe something along the lines of (no specific server-side language)

```
$name = "Events";

print '<a class="t-link" href="#TabStrip-5" id="' .  strtolower($name) . '-link">' . $name . '</a>
```

Comment: the tabs are dynamic, so Events may move to other position

Comment: the li element is auto generated by Telerik tabstrip control, I don't kno If I can control that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but why don't you use an attribute selector?

```
$('a[href*="#TabStrip"])…
```